# Hibernate and strange OneToMany behaviour

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate

I'm currently on `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:2.7.0` which uses `hibernate:5.6.9`.

I've got a strange behavior when chaining multiple entities.

I got three Entities, where `E1` contains a OneToMany-List of `E2` which also contains a OneToMany-List of `E3`:

```java
    @Entity
    public class E1 {
      @Id
      @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
      @Column(name = "id", nullable = false, updatable = false)
      UUID id;
    
      @OneToMany(mappedBy = "e1", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
      List<E2> e2;
    }
```

```java
    @Entity
    public class E2 {
      @Id
      @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
      @Column(name = "id", nullable = false, updatable = false)
      UUID id;

      @ManyToOne
      E1 e1;
    
      @OneToMany(mappedBy = "e2", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
      List<E3> e3;
    }
```

```java
    @Entity
    public class E3 {
      @Id
      @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
      @Column(name = "id", nullable = false, updatable = false)
      UUID id;

      @ManyToOne
      E2 e2;
    }
```

For each entity I defined simple repositories like:

```java
@Repository
public interface E1Repository extends JpaRepository<E1, UUID> {}
```

Additionally I got according repository classes to access the date. Storing is fine and works fine.

When storing one `E1` with a list of one `E2` having a list of two `E3` leads to the proper data in my database table.

Retrieving the data using `e1Repository.findAll()` is fine and returns the expected Entity `e1` with **one** `e2` and two `e3`.

However when retrieving the data using `e1Repository.findById(id)` it returns one `e1` entity with **two** `e2` each containing two `e3`. The two `e2` are both the same with the same ID.

When changing the `List<E?>` to a `Set<E?>` it works correctly, but is just a workaround.

Has anyone an explanation for this behavior? What am I doing wrong or what can I change to get my data right?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use @JoinColumn instead of mappedBy.